# Web view crash on Atrix while hiding scroll bar

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using a web view in my layout. As you know there is an issue where you see a white line on the right hand side of the web view. This is because of the scroll bar that is added to the web view.

Now you can hide this scroll bar in two ways

1. `webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);`
2. `webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);`
   `webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);`

But the problem is when I do that my application crashes on Android Atrix phone. If I comment out these lines it works fine.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Please add crash log from `LogCat`